# Need a regular expression that matches “word1, word2, word3”

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to construct a regular expression that would match a pattern as such:

```
word1, word2, word3
```

So basically I want "`,` " to appear twice and to have words between them. So far I came up with:

```
$general_content_check = preg_match("/^.*, .*$/", $general_content);
```

But this matches only "`,` " several times in a string.

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
"/^\w+, \w+, \w+$/"
```

Answer (score 7):

It depends what you mean by "word" but you can start by trying this:

```
^[^,]+(?:, +[^,]+){2}$
```

Explanation:

```
^          Start of line/string.
[^,]+      A "word" (anything that isn't a comma - including whitespace, etc.)
(?:        Start non-capturing group
    , +    A comma then any number of spaces
    [^,]+  A word
)          Close group
{2}        Repeat group exactly two times
$          End of line/string.
```

Other possible definitions of "word":

- Anything except whitespace or comma: `[^\s,]+`
- Only letters in A-Z: `[A-Z]+` (optionally add case-insensitive flag)
- Any letter in Unicode in any language: `\p{L}+` (not widely supported)
- Etc...

Comment: Good explanation of the code. Very helpful for budding programmers that need such explanations.